# Running a command for each line of a text file (Bash)

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am working on a program that does the following:

Reads 270 file in the folder X and calls another program to run a command with the contents of the file. For example:

```
$ cat X/1.txt
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
```

The program is supposed to read that text (there are 270 of them) and in the loop it's supposed to do:

```
$python file.py AAAA;
```

then

```
python file.py BBBB;
```

then

```
python file.py CCCC.
```

and the move on the next file like 22.txt (the files aren't numeric so a counter wouldn't be much help).

I tried the following:

```
function text(){
for i in $(ls Domains/);
while read line;
do
        $line
        f= done < Domains/$i.txt
        python file.py $f
}

text;
```

Thanks, guys!

Comment: Not like that (ignore this comment)

Comment: It seems like every second bash-tagged question I see here needs someone to point out the dangers of [parsing LS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  Please read the link, and don't do what you're doing.  And read about `find` and its `-exec` option, that's in the direction of what you want to use.

Answer (score 3):

This is where `xargs` comes in handy: Concatenate all the files and pipe that into xargs which feeds each line to the python program one by one.

```
cat * | xargs -L1 python file.py
```

Comment: From what I have read online, it is advised not to ever use cat for things like that.. makes things messy.. but +1 for xargs!

Comment: @user3610137: On the contrary, that's an excellent use of `cat`. In contrast, you should not do this: `for i in $(ls Domains/);` which will fail when files have whitespace or glob characters in their names. `for i in *;` is preferred. If you don't care which file a line comes from, though, `cat * |` is simple and reliable, unless your directories have tens of thousands of files in them.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function text(){
for i in $(ls Domains/)
do
while read line;
do
python file.py $line
done < Domains/$i.txt   
done     
}
```

Comment: is it possible to dump the output for each file in it's own text file?

Comment: Yes, first collect all the outputs in a variable or in a separate file, then dump it in the text file after the text file is finished being used (after the while loop).

Comment: How? I tried adding

 done < Domains/$i.txt > $i-DONE.txt but that doesn't work.

Comment: That's not how you get output.. Your output will be produced by python file.py $line, redirect them to another file.

Comment: I'm trying to run python file and put the ouput of that in it's own file.. so run python file.py $line of each .txt file and dump the output into $i-OUTPUT.txt

Comment: change the python... line to: `output+=$(python file.py $line)`
then after `done < Domains/$i.txt ` add this:
`echo "$output" >> "$i.txt"`
and also flush output variable adding `output=""` after this line